# There exists infinitely many solutions of $xy'=4y$ that satisfies $y(a)=b$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential Equations By Henry Edwards:

Given, $y(x)=Cx^4$ defines a one-parameter family of differentiable solutions of the differential equation $xy'=4y$.
For any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, explain why there exists infinitely many differentiable solutions of $xy'=4y$ that all satisfy the condition $y(a)=b$

I know any solution of the differential equation is of the form $y(x)=Cx^4$.

So,$y(a)=C(a)^4$

If I take $C=\frac{b}{a^4}$,then $y(a)=\frac{b}{a^4}.a^4=b$

So, $y(x)=(\frac{b}{a^4})x^4$ is the only one solution of $xy'=4y$ that satisfies $y(a)=b$

But they saying there exists infinitely many solutions of $xy'=4y$ that satisfies $y(a)=b$?
How can I show there exists infinitely many solutions of $xy'=4y$ that satisfies $y(a)=b$?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Each function
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases}
C^{-}x^4 \;\; \text{for} \;\; x<0 \\
C^{+}x^4 \;\; \text{for} \;\; x\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable and satisfies $xy'=4y.$

If $a<0,$ you only need to fix $C^{-}$ and can use any value for $C^{+}.$ Likewise, if $a>0,$ you only need to fix $C^{+}$ and can use any value for $C^{-}.$

If $a=0$ and $b=0$, then $C^{-}$ and $C^{+}$ can take any value.

If $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$, then there is no solution.

Comment: If for $a=0\ and\ b\neq 0$ there is no solution,then isn't it false  that " for any real numbers $a\ and\ b$ there exists infinitely many differentiable solutions of $xy'=4y$ that satisfies $y(a)=b$".

Comment: So, Can I say, the question is wrong??

Comment: @mathstudent Yes, exactly. If $a=0$ and $b\neq 0,$ then the question would require us to fulfill $0 = 0\cdot y'(a) = 4b \neq 0,$ which is obviously impossible.